# Natural deduction proof of ¬p ∨ q ⊢ ¬(¬p → q)

Tags: natural-deduction

I am working through some natural deduction proofs and found this question:

¬p ∨ q ⊢ ¬(¬p → q)

I can quite easily get to ¬¬(p → q) using the ¬¬i rule, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if the question perhaps contains a typo.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry again, you were right: it is not valid. Check it with both $p$ and $q$ True.

Comment: All good, thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA for confirming. I see exactly what you mean as well. I'm declaring this to be a typo then. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA for assisting - we have agreed that the question contains a typo. My assumption is that the question was meant to be as follows:

¬p ∨ q ⊢ ¬¬(p → q)

Comment: "⊢"  does this symbol mean "implies $\implies$"

Comment: No - that symbol is called a turnstile, and it means "proves" - therefore, a ⊢ b is equivalent to "a proves b"